При попытке открыть новое диалоговое окно программа замораживается
Вот код, который затрагивает проблему:
Файл mainWindow:
class Ui_MainWindow:
    def setupUi(self):
        # описание интерфейса

    # несколько методов не относящиеся к данной проблеме
    
    def openNewDialog():
        self.newWindow = QDialog()
        self.uiParametersConfig = Ui_Dialog()
        self.uiParametersConfig.setupUi(self.newWindow)
        # здесь вся программа останавливается
        self.newWindow.show()

Файл main:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
def keyboardEventsLoop():
    keyboard.wait('сочетание клавиш')
    window.ui.openNewDialog()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpCaller = callToSpotifyAPI.SpCaller()
    SpCaller.initMainWindow()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showFullScreen()

    keyboardEventsLoopThread = threading.Thread(target = keyboardEventsLoop)

    keyboardEventsLoopThread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

Если убрать потоки программа исправно работает, но как тогда повесить обработчик нажатий на клавиатуру. Ещё я пробовал реализовать всё в QThread, результат остался тем же

Любой известный GUI однопоточный. Нельзя его дёргать из дополнительных потоков. Используйте для обработки событий клавиатуры специальные события самого фреймворка, в частности keyPressEvent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050466/pyside6-respond-to-keyboard-input

Chelovek, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.
